# how make wpf app in blend that come with Visual studio 2012 express edition

Tags: wpf, blend, visual-studio-express

I have Visual studio 2012 express edition sp2 that come with blend for Windows 8 app and windows phone and my question why I can not maka wpf application in blend,
WPF is not exist in new project in blend

Answer (score 0):

You need to download Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop in order to create WinForms and WPF applications.